# Django migrations build_graph has a bug?

Tags: python, django, database-migration

Running my tests after squashing migrations I get this error report:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py:220: KeyError
```

Here's the source code:

```
def build_graph(self):
    """
        Builds a migration dependency graph using both the disk and database.
        You'll need to rebuild the graph if you apply migrations. This isn't
        usually a problem as generally migration stuff runs in a one-shot process.
        """
    # Load disk data
    self.load_disk()
    # Load database data
    if self.connection is None:
        self.applied_migrations = set()
    else:
        recorder = MigrationRecorder(self.connection)
        self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
    # Do a first pass to separate out replacing and non-replacing migrations
    normal = {}
    replacing = {}
    for key, migration in self.disk_migrations.items():
        if migration.replaces:
            replacing[key] = migration
        else:
            normal[key] = migration
    # Calculate reverse dependencies - i.e., for each migration, what depends on it?
    # This is just for dependency re-pointing when applying replacements,
    # so we ignore run_before here.
    reverse_dependencies = {}
    for key, migration in normal.items():
        for parent in migration.dependencies:
            reverse_dependencies.setdefault(parent, set()).add(key)
    # Carry out replacements if we can - that is, if all replaced migrations
    # are either unapplied or missing.
    for key, migration in replacing.items():
        # Ensure this replacement migration is not in applied_migrations
        self.applied_migrations.discard(key)
        # Do the check. We can replace if all our replace targets are
        # applied, or if all of them are unapplied.
        applied_statuses = [(target in self.applied_migrations) for target in migration.replaces]
        can_replace = all(applied_statuses) or (not any(applied_statuses))
        if not can_replace:
            continue
        # Alright, time to replace. Step through the replaced migrations
        # and remove, repointing dependencies if needs be.
        for replaced in migration.replaces:
            if replaced in normal:
                # We don't care if the replaced migration doesn't exist;
                # the usage pattern here is to delete things after a while.
                del normal[replaced]
            for child_key in reverse_dependencies.get(replaced, set()):
                if child_key in migration.replaces:
                    continue
                normal[child_key].dependencies.remove(replaced)
```

The last line throws this:

```
KeyError: ('my_app', u'0001_initial')
```

You see the problem is that `child_key` is not present in the `normal` dictionary. The previous line is checking if child_key is in migrations.replaces because in this case it is possible that the child_key migrations has already been removed. However it is possible that the child_key is in the replaces of another migration and hence anyway it could be already been removed even if it is not in migration.replaces.

Do you agree this is a bug in django code?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I was squashing several applications and suddenly started getting this error. I'll try to debug it assuming the problem is in the last squased app.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23733) in Django 1.7. From the bug report, it looks like [the fix](https://github.com/django/django/commit/fd061b6591ddc0b3045661ff22243919a7c76f17) was part of Django 1.8. We're going to wait until we upgrade Django before squashing more migrations.